# Maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]/(\sqrt 2)$ is isomorphic to set of all integers, which is not a field. But $(\sqrt 2)$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ (since in a P.I.D every prime ideal is maximal). So the quotient has to be a field.
But why does it contradict the fact that R/I is a field if and only if I is a maximal ideal in ring R.

Comment: You may have noticed that your `<sqrt2>` disappeared. That's because that's what happens with anything put between `<` and `>` on this site if you're not careful. Instead, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math properly so that it appears at all and as a bonus is readable (use the commands `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`; it looks better).

Answer (score 7):

$\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]/(\sqrt2)\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ *is* a field (note that $2\in (\sqrt2)$, which makes this case different from $\Bbb Z[x]/(x)\cong \Bbb Z$ since $(x)$ doesn't contain any non-zero integers).